# transform json object to an array field

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I want to transform a list of objects with object having this form

```
{
    "idActivite": 1,
    "nomActivite": "Accueil des participants autour d’un café viennoiseries",
    "descriptionActivite": "",
    "lieuActivite": "",
    "typeActivite": "",
    "horaireDebActivite": 1512028800,
    "horaireFinActivite": 1512059388,
    "horaireDebSession": 1512030600,
    "horaireFinSession": 1512318588,
    "nomSession": "",
    "isInSession": false
}
```

to a one like this :

```
[
    "idActivite": 1,
    "nomActivite": "Accueil des participants autour d’un café viennoiseries",
    "descriptionActivite": "",
    "lieuActivite": "",
    "typeActivite": "",
    "horaireDebActivite": 1512028800,
    "horaireFinActivite": 1512059388,
    "horaireDebSession": 1512030600,
    "horaireFinSession": 1512318588,
    "nomSession": "",
    "isInSession": false
]
```

using type script 2.5

Comment: The "result" is a syntax error

Comment: An array can only have numeric "keys". What's your real question - you have a typescript file requiring an array for an argument and instead you are passing in an object? Maybe your function is meant to contain a list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are theoretically still objects and that isnt the right way to go about it! An array is simply a list of elements with a number index, the example you are giving uses a string to index and thus is still according to the JSON spec an object. If the issue you are having is to iterate through it use this:

```
for(var key in array){
  console.log(array[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an array like [ {key, value} ]

```
let x = { a: 1, b: 2 }
let y = []

// Note the 'in' keyword instead of 'of'
for (const key in x) {
    y.push({ key: key, value: x[key] })
}

// Will print [ { key: 'a', value: 1 }, { key: 'b', value: 2 } ]
console.log(y)
```

Note that this solution scales linearly with the size of the array.